# Static type class in relation to pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, static, overriding

I'm seriously confused over static and dynamic types in C++. In the following example, why are the Account pointers considered static?

```
class Account{
    public:
      virtual string getType() { return "Generic Account"; };
  };

  class Current: public Account{
    public:
      virtual string getType() { return "Current Account"; };  
  };

  class Deposit: public Account{
    public:
      virtual string getType() { return "Deposit Account"; };  
  };

  int main()
  {
    // Note that all pointers have the static type Account
    Account *a = new Account(); 
    Account *b = new Current();
    Account *c = new Deposit();

    cout << "Pointer a Displayed: " << a->getType() << endl;
    cout << "Pointer b Displayed: " << b->getType() << endl;
    cout << "Pointer c Displayed: " << c->getType() << endl;
  }
```

Are all pointers of base class type static and all pointers of derived class dynamic? For example, would

> Current *d = new Deposit();

be dynamic as it's of a derived class type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using uncommon terms. What do you mean by "static" and "dynamic" pointers?

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language. If you are looking for dynamic types languages, look at something like Python. A pointer has one type, and one type only.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Pointers indeed have only one type. Polymorphic class instances, on the other hand, have dynamic types in addition to static ones.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know...

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as static or dynamic *pointers*.
But there are static and dynamic *types*.

---

Normally variables and expressions have only one type, which is also called a *static type*.
Polymorphic class instances additionally have *dynamic type*.

If an expression refers to an instance of a base class located inside of an instance of a derived class, then the dynamic type of the expression is that derived class.

---

An example should make this clear:

```
Account *a = new Account(); 
Account *b = new Current();
Account *c = new Deposit();
```

Here both `*a`, `*b`, and `*c` have the same static type - `Account`. Static type doesn't depend on what those pointers point to, only on how they were declared.

On the other hand, dynamic types of `*a`, `*b`, and `*c` are `Account`, `Current`, and `Deposit`, respectively. Dynamic type depends on what the pointers actually point to.